# Using itertools in Python password cracker

Tags: python, python-itertools, combinatorics

I made a simple password cracker:

```
import string as s
import itertools as it

things = s.ascii_letters

for digits in range(2, 6):
    for combo in it.combinations(things, digits):
        output = ''.join(combo)
        print(output)
```

but it doesn't print out all possibilities.

For example, the last output this program gives out is:

```
VWXYZ
```

If I had a password starting with "X", the program wouldn't be able to find it.

Is there any way I can fix this? What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `itertools.product()` with the `repeat` parameter. Using `itertools.combinations()` doesn't allow for the same letter to be selected more than once:

```py
import string as s
import itertools as it

things = s.ascii_letters

for digits in range(2, 6):
    for combo in it.product(things, repeat=digits):
        output = ''.join(combo)
        print(output)
```